# Linking errors only when using Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, linker, qt-creator, undefined-symbol

I have linking problems when I execute some code that links to different shared libraries. The fact is that I haven't them if I use the console, but only if I execute it within the Qt creator IDE.

Do you guys know if there a kind of console where I can use nm readelf and stuff like that with the QT build / runtime environment?

Alternatively, how would you debug such problem?

Specifically, the error I get is something like:

symbol lookup error: blabla undefined symbol: blabla

[EDIT] Suggested question is different in respect to what I'm asking. I'm specifically speaking about the qt creator environment, not linking errors in general. Specifically, it's about how to debug linking errors in qt creator when using the console everything seems ok.

Comment: Please edit your question and follow community guidelines

Comment: question edited.

Answer (score 1):

1) Can you explain a bit more in detail what you need?

2) Can you publish your .pro file generated by Qt Creator?

Comment: The problem with this is that qtcreator allows you to only specify the executable and the arguments. When you run the executable via qt, it starts a kind of shell and execute the binary in the environment  that you have specified. Problem is that if you have linking problems in that environment, it is much more difficult to understand why you have such problems because you don't have tools like nm ldd readelf etc.

Comment: I've been able to create a custom executable environment where I specifically launch ldd and my other target binary path as argument, but it is not the same as having a shell. I've also tried to launch a script, but again, it's not the same, because the script, for some reason, uses my real shell environment..